DCV ERROR: Failed to import "file" due to SCM error: "github.com/thursday/myrepo". name 'urllib3' is not defined
I tried using dvc to import my zipped data using the command:
`dvc import https://github.com/thursday/myrepo xyz.zip  -o data/myrepo/xyz.zip'.
This is my github :"https://github.com/Krishnamugundh/vocal_disease_prediction_app/blob/data/voice-icar-federico-ii-database-1.0.0.zip" file I'm trying to import. But, I received an error;
ERROR: failed to import 'xyz' - SCM error: Failed to clone repo 'https://github.com/thursday/myrepo' to 'C:\Users\thursday\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5pjwggyjdvc-clone': name 'urllib3' is not defined

Error Log here
Got stuck even after updating dvc and urllib3. Here are the versions details:dvc==3.51.2 && urllib3==2.0.2.

How do you install dvc? Could you run dvc version and include its output here please.

I think this is a misleading error, due to this issue https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/pull/1300
The new version of dulwich is not released yet.
To get an actual error, you can either install duliwch from the main brach (dev version), use debugger.
I think the actual issue is something related to auth. E.g. if repo is not public, you can't clone it w/o providing some kind of credentials. E.g. can you even run a command like:
git clone https://github.com/thursday/myrepo ?
How do you do auth with GitHub?
